# SQL schema Table compare

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, compare, database-schema

I'm looking for an app that will compare the layout of 2 SQL tables. When developing in a DEV environment, I need a tool that will make the production tables exactly like the DEV tables (the layout).

Comment: layout?  Do you mean the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Compare from Red Gate  and ERWin are two tools that work. Neither are free

Comment: We use SQL Compare on a regular basis to keep schemas in sync. It is available as a 14 day trial for those that want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program called "SQL Server Comparison Tool" (SCT for short).  You can try it for free for 30 days; I can extend that period to 90 days.

You can download SCT from www.sql-server-tool.com

SCT can compare both structure and data. You can "record" comparisons so that you can "re-play" them later without need for entering parameters again.

Answer (score 1):

BeyondCompare can do this for you I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [SQL Examiner](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Examiner/) tool from the [SQL Accessories](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/).